# What algorithms does the Rust compiler use to infer lifetime variables?

Tags: rust, type-inference, lifetime, unification

```
fn foo<'a>(x: &'a i32, y: &'a i32) {}

fn main() { 
    let a = 123;
    {
        let b = 234;
        foo(&a, &b);
    }
}
```

In the code above `&a` and `&b` should hopefully be references with different lifetimes.

How does the compiler infer the lifetime var `'a` for `foo`? As far as I can tell, it's not using a standard Hindley-Milner unification algorithm. The lifetime must be the inner scope or some intersection of the two lifetimes.

Is lifetime inference a completely separate process to the standard type inference?

Does the compiler use intersection types or use some sub-type relationship between lifetimes to choose the most restricted lifetime?

Answer (score 2):

Rust uses a modified Hindley-Milner unification algorithm because it has sub-typing relationships.

For example, `&'static T` is a sub-type of `&'a T` for any `'a`.

Your case is relatively easy, when the compiler sees the call `foo(&a, &b)` it just unifies `'a` as the most restrictive of both lifetimes (which is the intersection, since lifetimes are lexical for now).

Comment: Can you describe how it does this please. Specifically, the differences from standard Hindley-Milner.

Comment: (Algorithm W) .

Comment: @tm1rbrt: I'm woefully inadequate, it's also very much in flux. You may want to check out Niko Matsakis' new blog serie though: Unification in Chalk [Part 1](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2017/03/25/unification-in-chalk-part-1/) and [Part 2](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2017/04/23/unification-in-chalk-part-2/), where he is describing a new algorithm for unification he is working on and which he plans to transition the Rust compiler to (in part or in whole).